# NPE occurs in jsp when retrieving hidden field value

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

In my jsp i have two input fields and a button. Input fields values are set into two hidden fields. Button click event invokes a js function which try to retrieve hidden field values as below,

```
<% String wsdl1Path = request.getParameter("wsdl1path").toString();    
String    wsdl2Path = request.getParameter("wsdl2path").toString();    
WsdlCompare com = new WsdlCompare();    
String url = "";    
if ( wsdl1Path != null && wsdl2Path != null ) {    
url= com.compare(wsdl1Path,wsdl2Path);    
}
....
```

This cause the NPE. If handle the Exception, java method is not getting called.
Note : wsdl1path and wsdl2path : Ids of hidden fields

Error log:

```
[2014-12-10 23:08:11,077] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher} -  Servlet.service() for servlet bridgeservlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.wsdlcompare.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:179)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
.......
```

Comment: if either of the `wsdl1path` or `wsdl2path` parameters are not set, your `request.getParameter` will return `null`, thus causing NPE trying to invoke `toString()`

Comment: When page loads NPE is thrown. I try to handle it by catching the NPE using try catch. Then my java class method is not getting invoke.

Answer (score 0):

```
String wsdl1Path = request.getParameter("wsdl1path");
String wsdl2Path = request.getParameter("wsdl2path");

WsdlCompare com = new WsdlCompare();    
String url = "";    
if ( wsdl1Path != null && wsdl2Path != null ) {    
  url= com.compare(wsdl1Path,wsdl2Path);    
}else{
  //Handle NPE
}
```

Try this...

if wsdl1Path or wsdl2Path became null  you will able to handle the exception.

And also try passing your two parameters via GET or POST methods, if its GET load page with above two parameters.

Eg: `index.jsp?wsdl1Path=wsdl1_path&wsdl2Path=wsdl2_path`